# p-button-label class from primeng destroys button size dont understand why?

Tags: node.js, angular, primeng

Hi maybe anybody with primeng experince can help ?

I use primeng in my angular project and dont understand this issue...

if I create buttons out of the Primeng docs they will be displayed wrong

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row ">
        <div class="p-2 ml-auto">
            <button type="button" pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-file-o" (click)="exportCSV()" class="p-mr-2"
                pTooltip="CSV" tooltipPosition="bottom"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2">
            <button type="button" pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-file-excel" (click)="exportExcel()"
                class="p-button-success p-mr-2" pTooltip="XLS" tooltipPosition="bottom"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2">
            <button type="button" pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-file-pdf" (click)="exportPdf()"
                class="p-button-warning p-mr-2" pTooltip="PDF" tooltipPosition="bottom"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2">
            <button type="button" pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-filter" (click)="dt.exportCSV({selectionOnly:true})"
                class="p-button-info p-ml-auto" pTooltip="Selection Only" tooltipPosition="bottom"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Issue photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVsul.png)

Comment: Please provide the css of the classes refered to as well as "p-mr-2"

Comment: Found the solution! PrimeNG has two ways to create an button element



`<button type="button" pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-filter"
                class="p-button-info p-ml-auto"></button>`

if we use the above one you have to declare label="text" because if its empty prime ng will write an label with &nbsp which is the text symbol for space. 

In my Case that space made my buttons look like the above example picture.



 `<p-button pRipple icon="pi pi-file-pdf" styleClass="p-button-warning p-mr-2"
                    pTooltip="PDF" tooltipPosition="bottom"></p-button>`